# Edgeworth Economy and Walras equilibrium

Tags: microeconomics, walrasian, edgeworth-box

I have been given an Edgeworth Economy with to consumers A and B. Their preferences are given with the utility functions:

[image]
[image]

My question is, how do I find the walras equilibrium? I tried starting out with finding the marshallian demand, but my result turned out not making sense. Would someone not mind to help?

Comment: The total initial endowment for the economy satisfies e1=e2.  The income for consumer A is given as the part k of the total resources, which means I=(p1+p2)ke. Cosumer B is given the income I=(p1+p2)(1-k)e

Comment: "*I tried starting out with finding the marshallian demand, but my result turned out not making sense.*" That is the way, so you should probably take another crack at that part, maybe go over your notes for marshallian demand again.

Comment: You can watch this video. It might help: https://youtu.be/9B_vymYtol0